# Add retina "2x" in attribute "srcset"

Tags: images, retina

I need to add the "2x" to the url attribute `srcset` in wordpress 4.4.2.
Maybe you can do so using a function in the `functions.php` file?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

WordPress puts all resized versions of an image with the same aspect ratio into the `srcset` property. So if you need a "2x" image and one is not being generated already you could add an image size via [`add_image_size()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_image_size/).

For the 2x image to be inserted in the correct circumstances you might need to tweak the `sizes` property via the [`wp_calculate_image_sizes`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_calculate_image_sizes/) filter.